# Theoretical break frequency and bandwidth of notch filter

Tags: filter, analysis, bandwidth

I'm trying to learn how to calculate the bandwidth and break frequency for the notch filter shown below. I was told that wye-delta and delta-wye transformation would be needed, but don't fully understand where to go.

[image: Notch Filter]

Below is some of my work thus far for simplifying the circuit to get the transfer function
note: C1 and C2 represent the frequency transformed impedances of their equivalent capacitors; ie, C1 = 1/(1uF *s)
note 2: T-structures should be labeled \$\Pi\$-structures).

[image: Transforms]

Taking the Wye-like Structure and Delta transforming the lower-wye, then combining the C2 impedance with the top impedance of the new delta structure, I was able to achieve the following (intermediate) transfer function:

[image: Transform Function]

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent on-line calculator [here](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/TwinTCRkeisan.htm) which contains all the formulas for a twin T notch filter - your circuit isn't a twin T but you can use the formulas as shown below: -

[image]

Firstly R3 can be assumed to be infinite and secondly C2 and C3 can be both assumed to be 200nF thus making 100nF in total.

I reckon your filter is notching at 250Hz (according to the online calculator). Good luck with calculating the bandwidth from the formula.

**EDIT** Here is a start for you: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :) According to SPICE and experimental results, the center frequency is 250 Hz. As far as I know, I am required to derive the transfer function from analysis. My professor showed it and it was 3 pages long. Some help with that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: You could at least upvote before asking for 3 pages of transfer function. :D

Comment: @Andy aka. I've struggled to reach the notch frequency expression. I've used MATLAB in order to derive the transfer function but after that I'm not being able to derive the notch filter expression. Is there any way you can help me out with that?

Comment: @IronMaiden I suggest you open a new question and show where you got to working things out by yourself and ask for help in proceeding.